# Массив в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте!
Помогите мне, пожалуйста, вот у меня есть двумерный массив мне нужно создать второй массив и скопировать туда содержимое первого в обратном порядке! помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @timka, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом/функцией (не уверен как правильно в javascript это называется) [reverse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)

```
arr = [1,2,3]
a = arr.reverse() // в "а" у вас теперь будет массив [3,2,1]
```

Comment: Извеняюсь есть впрака не написал нужно без каких либо методов в цикле это всё сделать

Comment: У меня есть двумерный массив мне нужно создать второй массив в него скопироваить в обратном порядке содержимое первго массива при помощи цикла, помагите пожалуйста

Comment: @timka, а  как делать для одномерного массива - понимаете?

Для двумерного - аналогично, только индексов два, а не один.

Comment: не могли бы вы показать примерно как это выглядит в коде?

Comment: Смотрите (псевдокод), вот у Вас 2 массива A[N] и B[N] (индексируются с 0, т.е. содержат элементы A[0], A[1], ... A[N-1]), код

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      B[i] = A[i];

скопирует массив A в массив B, а код
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      B[N - 1 - i] = A[i];

скопирует массив A в массив B в обратном порядке.

Если у нас двумерные массивы A[N][M] и B[N][M], то 

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        B[i][j] = A[i][j];

копирует двумерный массив A в B в прямом порядке.

--

А теперь, по аналогии, напишите сами копирование в обратном порядке.

Comment: А как реализовать при помощи среза?

Comment: Вот только и в `arr` тоже теперь будет `[3,2,1]`