# Как вывести вложенный массив наоборот?

Tags: javascript

```
const a = [
  [1,2,3],
  ['a',5,'c',],
  [ 4,5,6],
  ['d','e','f'],
  [ 7,8,9],
];
```

Comment: Покажите желаемый результат, а то непонятно, какое именно «наоборот» имеется в виду

Comment: Похожие вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/265500/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4/265528) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230268/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5/230269)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так же как и невложенный:

```js
const a = [
  [1,2,3],
  ['a',5,'c',],
  [ 4,5,6],
  ['d','e','f'],
  [ 7,8,9],
];
a.forEach(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item.reverse())));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [
  [1,2,3],
  ['a',5,'c',],
  [ 4,5,6],
  ['d','e','f'],
  [ 7,8,9],
];

console.log(a.map(m => m.reverse()))
```